# How to Replace a Trunk with a Branch using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to replace the trunk with a branch using TortoiseSVN?

Comment: Do you mean merging, or actually replacing?

Comment: I wish to replace the trunk but keep a branch/tag of the existing trunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Tortoise svn, You can go to trunk, right click and select Copy to.

then, it will ask the url. So, you can put your branch url there.

Comment: Doesn't that replace the branch with the trunk?

Answer (score 10):

Move the current trunk to some other place (/branch/oldtrunk), then move /branch/mybranch to /trunk, then move /branch/oldtrunk to /branch

With the command line client, this can be done with:

```
svn mv http://path/to/repo/trunk http://path/to/repo/branch/oldtrunk
svn mv http://path/to/repo/branch/mybranch http://path/to/repo/trunk
svn mv http://path/to/repo/branch/oldtrunk http://path/to/repo/branch/mybranch
```

Good luck!

Comment: Is there a command(menu option) where this can be achieved directly from *TortoiseSVN*?

Comment: Yes, take a look: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html But I think, the comand tool is sure - you know what you do ;)

Comment: the full svn mv command will be the following:
`svn mv http://path/to/repo/trunk http://path/to/repo/branch/oldtrunk -m "you comment"`